# Open an advertisement in a new page when it is clicked

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Currently, we need to use the back button to return to a question after clicking on an advertisement.

Comment: ...or: hold down Ctrl or Command while clicking, or use the middle mouse button.

Comment: @Arjan: Don't forget `Shift`.

Answer (score 11):

No, please, no. I want to decide when a link opens in a new window/tab.